# In App Purchase in Android: Error response: 7 Item already owned

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I released beta version of my app to playstore and I have implemented In-App purchases in my app. When I purchase the item for first time it is working fine and try to purchase again it is showing an error response as:

```
In-app billing error: Unable to buy item, Error response: 7:Item Already Owned.
```

I created a sample project and published to playstore with In-App purchase implementation. For published app the item purchasing working as expected for multiple times. But in Beta version app I'am unable to purchase an item for the second time. Its not even initiating the process of purchasing.

Why I'am unable to purchase an item for the second time in Beta version app?

Answer (score 1):

because the item is non consumable in the google play console, this means that you can only purchase the item one item and after that you can not. if you want to enable the user to purchase the item more than one time you have to make the item on google play console as "consumable" then you will be able to purchase it as you want.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html

Comment: Do I need to make the items consumable on Google Play Console? OR Am'I missing anything in my code?

Comment: OR Is it so because of Beta release?

Comment: try to make the item consumable in google console and see

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of products subscriptions and managed products. Managed products can be consumed. You must send a consumption request (`consumePurchase` call) to Google Play before purchase an item for the second time. Check [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#consume).